# Why is GLEE failing with glClearIuiEXT()?

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to test using GLEE for the first time. I seem to be following the book fine. However, this condition passes, but the function does not set the clear value. At least, I get a black screen. glClearColor works, however.

```
if (GLEE_VERSION_2_0 && GLEE_EXT_texture_integer)
    glClearColorIuiEXT(128,128,128,255);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glClearColorI*` is for clearing *integer textures*, i.e. ones where sampling produce an integer value instead of a normalized value from 0 through 1. It will not work for regular, normalized textures or renderbuffers, like the one most likely allocated by your window.

Use the regular `glClearColor` method instead. Divide the value by `255` if you must.

Comment: **+1**: Just to avoid confusion (no need to change your answer), `glClearColorI` was never promoted to core GL. The whole idea behind setting "clear values" was abandoned when Framebuffer Objects were promoted to core in GL3. The modern equivalent of this is to do something like `GLuint color [] = { 128, 128, 128, 255 }; glClearBufferuiv (GL_COLOR, 0 /* glDrawBuffer 0 */,  color);` Conveniently, that establishes the value to clear and does the clearing all in one call. That is definitely not what the OP wants, but it's why you don't see many questions about `glClearColorI*` ;)